# SQL - Join two tables and count different things

Tags: sql

I have two tables TEILNEHMERKURS and KURS.

Kurs:

```
| Bezeichnung      | 
| ---------------- |
| Java Programming | 
| Java Programming | 
| Database         |
```

and the second Table TEILNEHMERKURS

```
| Bezeichnung      | 
| ---------------- |
| Database         | 
| Java Programming | 
| Database         |
```

And I need a Statment to generate following output:

```
| Bezeichnung      | Count in Table Kurs |Count in Table Teilnehmerkurs
| ---------------- |-------------------- |-----------------------------
| Database         | 1                   |2
| Java Programming | 2                   |1
```

I tried following statement:

```
select k.bezeichnung, count(k.bezeichnung), count(tk.bezeichnung)
from kurs k
    left join teilnehmerkurs tk on tk.kursnr = k.kursnr
group by k.bezeichnung;
```

and my actual output is:

```
| Bezeichnung      | Count in Table Kurs |Count in Table Teilnehmerkurs
| ---------------- |-------------------- |-----------------------------
| Database         | 2                   |2
| Java Programming | 2                   |1
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: select k.bezeichnung, count(k.bezeichnung), count(tk.bezeichnung)
from kurs k
    left join teilnehmerkurs tk on tk.kursnr = k.kursnr
group by k.bezeichnung;

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think it as an Oracle Server. Sorry that I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FULL JOIN` after `group by`separately.

```
DECLARE @Kurs TABLE ( Bezeichnung VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Kurs VALUES 
('Java Programming'),
('Java Programming'),
('Database')

DECLARE @TEILNEHMERKURS TABLE( Bezeichnung VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @TEILNEHMERKURS VALUES
('Database'),
('Java Programming'),
('Database')


SELECT COALESCE(K.Bezeichnung, T.Bezeichnung) Bezeichnung
    , K.[Count in Table Kurs]
    , T.[Count in Table Teilnehmerkurs] 
FROM 
    (SELECT Bezeichnung, COUNT(*) [Count in Table Kurs] FROM @Kurs GROUP BY Bezeichnung ) K
    FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT Bezeichnung, COUNT(*) [Count in Table Teilnehmerkurs] FROM @TEILNEHMERKURS GROUP BY Bezeichnung) T
    ON K.Bezeichnung = T.Bezeichnung
```

Result:

```
Bezeichnung          Count in Table Kurs Count in Table Teilnehmerkurs
-------------------- ------------------- -----------------------------
Database             1                   2
Java Programming     2                   1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky.  A pretty fool-proof method is `union all` and `group by`:

```
select Bezeichnung, sum(inkurs), sum(inTeilnehmerkurs)
from ((select Bezeichnung, count(*) as inkurs, 0 as inTeilnehmerkurs
       from kurs
       group by Bezeichnung
      ) union all
      (select Bezeichnung, 0 as inkurs, count(*) as inTeilnehmerkurs
       from Teilnehmerkurs
       group by Bezeichnung
      )
     ) kt
group by Bezeichnung;
```

If you use a `join` to bring the results together, then you have to be careful about missing `Bezeichnung` in either table.  If you use a `full outer join`, then you need to use `coalesce()`.

Comment: I had tried this: select k.bezeichnung, count(k.bezeichnung), count(tk.bezeichnung)
from kurs k
    left join teilnehmerkurs tk on tk.kursnr = k.kursnr
group by k.bezeichnung;

Comment: @StefanLeith . . . That is not the answer that I'm suggesting.  Did you try this answer?

Comment: Yeah i tried your answer and it worked. Thank you! The reason why I posted my try is that you write in your answer, if I use a join than i should use coalesce(), but I had tried this but it didn't work. Maybe you can help me with my try.

Comment: @StefanLeith . . . My recommendation is to use `group by` with `union all`, which is why I don't elaborate on that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use select union for obtain all the Bezeichnung from both the table and then left join the count

```
  select t.Bezeichnung, tk.count_in_kurs, tt.count_in_teilnehmerkurs
  from (
  select Bezeichnung
  from Kurs
  union 
  select Bezeichnung
  from TEILNEHMERKURS) 
  left join (
  select Bezeichnung, count(*) as count_in_kurs
  from kurs 
  group by Bezeichnung
  ) tk on t.Bezeichnung = tk.Bezeichnung
  left join (
  select Bezeichnung, count(*) as count_in_TEILNEHMERKURS
  from kurs 
  group by Bezeichnung
  ) tt on t.Bezeichnung = tt.Bezeichnung
```